# Apache ReWrite rules with directories

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a .htaccess file that uses the below rewrite rule.

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/$ index.php?action=$1
```

This rule works and rewrites a http://url.com/doSomething to http://url.com/index.php?action=doSomething

In this same file I have rewrite rules for sub directories, such as:

```
RewriteRule ^news/([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/$ news/index.php?action=$1
```

On my local Xampp installation, when I go to http://url.com/news/ (which is a sub-directory) it loads the index.php file in the sub-directory. When I've uploaded this to my hosted web server, the original re-write rule takes precedence not passing onto the sub-directory.

Is there an option I'm missing to allow the original way that the rules were designed?

Please let me know if anything above doesn't make sense!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create `.htaccess` with only one rule, and place in `/` as well as sub-directories you want to re-write.

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/$ index.php?action=$1
```

So,

place `.htaccess` at `/.htaccess`

place `.htaccess` at `/news/.htaccess`

Comment: It's already like this unfortunately, thank you for the reply though!

Comment: Try writing only one rule, `RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/$ index.php?action=$1` and create individual `.htaccess` . place one in / and another in "news" directory. And then check, what happend.

Comment: Have you allowed the htaccess override in your vhost/apache config?

AllowOverride All

Comment: Hello, sorry I was in meetings all of yesterday afternoon. I'll update you shortly!